# Continuous in Zariski topology of $\Bbb{C}^n$ implies continuous in the Euclidean topology?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $I,J$ be two ideal in $\Bbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ let $f:Z(I)\to Z(J)\subset \Bbb{C}^n$ be an isomorphism of variety. I want to prove when endowed with Euclidean topology, $f$ is homeomorphism in that space.

---

My attempt, since the morphism of an algebraic variety it will induce morphism between regular function $$f^*:O_{Z(J)}(Z(J))\to O_{Z(I)}(Z(I))$$
pick the coordinate function $x_i$ then $$f^*(x_i) = x_i\circ f = f^i\in O_{Z(I)}(Z(I))$$ which is continuous in Zariski topology as a regular function. However I needs to prove it's continus in Euclidean topology. How can I prove it?

Comment: It is quite false that a Zariski-continuous function is continuous in the Euclidean topology. But $f$ is a *polynomial*, which is a much stronger condition; it is smooth and even analytic.

Comment: Hi @Qiaochu Yuan  , then continuous of $(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto (f_1(x_1,...), ... , f_n(x_1.,,,))$ can be checked locally while locally each $f_i$ is the quotient of two polynomial, with the demoninator non vanishing therefore is continuous , is my understanding correct? and the counterexample is $\sin (2\pi z) : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ while preimage of $0$ is $\Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{C}$ which is not Zariski closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds a bit more generally, and I think the explanation gets a bit cleaner: Say $I \subset \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ and $J \subset \mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m]$ are ideals, and
$$f: V(I) \to V(J)$$
is an isomorphism of affine varieties. Then $f$ induces an isomorphism of rings
$$\varphi = f^*: \mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m]/ \sqrt{J} \to \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n] / \sqrt{I}.$$
Composing with the projection $\mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m] \to \mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m] / \sqrt{J}$ yields a homomorphism $\overline \psi: \mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m] \to \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n] / \sqrt{I}$. If we choose preimages $a_i \in \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ of $\overline \psi(y_i)$, we can lift $\overline \psi$ to a homomorphism
$$\psi: \mathbb C[y_1, \dotsc, y_m] \to \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n],$$
which defines a polynomial map
$$g: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^m, (x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \mapsto (a_1(x), \dots, a_m(x)).$$

*Exercise:* Check that $g$ restricted to $V(I)$ is $f$.

Because $g$ is polynomial, it is continuous (even smooth, analytic) with respect to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb C^n$. Hence the same is true for  its restriction $f$.

Comment: great answer , thank you red_trumpet